# DirectSoundOut doesn't work but WaveOut does

Tags: naudio

Sending the microphone out to a DirectSoundOut doesn't work with this code:

```
        // directsound - doesn't work
        var mic = new WaveInEvent() { DeviceNumber = 0 };

        WaveInProvider waveInProvider = new WaveInProvider(mic);

        var dso = new DirectSoundOut(DirectSoundOut.DSDEVID_DefaultPlayback, 300);

        dso.Init(waveInProvider);
        mic.StartRecording();

        dso.Play();
```

But nearly the same things works with WaveOut:

```
        var mic = new WaveInEvent() { DeviceNumber = 0 }; 
        WaveInProvider waveInProvider = new WaveInProvider(mic);
        mic.StartRecording();
        var waveOut = new WaveOutEvent();
        waveOut.DeviceNumber = -1;
        waveOut.DesiredLatency = 300;
        waveOut.Init(waveInProvider);
        waveOut.Play();
```

NAudio: version 1.8.4
OS: Win 10 64bit

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I had the same problem.
Use this:

```
var mic = new WaveInEvent() { DeviceNumber = 0 };

    WaveInProvider waveInProvider = new WaveInProvider(mic);

    var dso = new DirectSoundOut(DirectSoundOut.DSDEVID_DefaultPlayback, 300);

    dso.Init(waveInProvider);
    mic.StartRecording();

    dso.Play();
    while(true) {}
```